# Cursor not returning any value,it is showing error?

Tags: android-sqlite

Am calling readPlaceName  from  TourGuideController, and passing the string in method readPlaceName(Placename), the cursor is showing null pointer exeception, not showing any values,Can any give solution for this error?

TourGuideController.java

```
public Cursor readPlaceName(String place_name){


    String sql = "SELECT  * FROM " + TourGuideDatabasehandler.VISTING_INBETWEEN_PLACES +
    " WHERE "+ TourGuideDatabasehandler.PLACE_NAME + " = '" + place_name+"'";
    Log.e("","Sql "+sql); 
     Cursor v = database.rawQuery(sql,null);
     Log.e("v","Cursor v : "+v.toString());

     return v;


}
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);



             int time = t_time;
             TourGuideController dbcon =  new TourGuideController(ourcontext);
             System.out.println("dbcon"+dbcon+"temp_dbcon"+dbcon);
                Log.e("OPEN","DB OPEN "+dbcon);



                String place = "Juhu Beach";
                Cursor cursors = dbcon.readPlaceName(place);

                Log.e("dpopen", "cursor"+cursors);

                Log.e("Updating cursor and cursor", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursors));


                Integer wait_time = null;

                while(cursors.moveToNext())
                {
                    wait_time = Integer.parseInt(cursors.getString(8));

                }

                     cursors.close(); 

                     String google_distance_time = "5";

                     Integer google_time = null;
                     google_time = Integer.parseInt(google_distance_time);

                     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                     DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
                     LocalTime time1 = formatter.parseLocalTime(start_time);

                     System.out.println("wait_time"+wait_time);
                     int pred_time = (wait_time) + (google_time);


                     int get_total_time = (time)-(pred_time);
                     total_time = String.valueOf(get_total_time);

                     int addTimeMin = pred_time;
                     time1 = time1.plusMinutes(addTimeMin);
                     prediction_time = String.valueOf(time1);

                     dbcon.updateDateTime(place, start_date, start_time,google_distance_time,prediction_time,total_time);
                     Cursor cursor2 = dbcon.readPlaceName(place);

                     Log.e("Updating time and date", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor2));



        }
                    }}
```

Comment: do you realize that you are leaking `cursor2`?

Comment: also, what's happening in `dbcon.updateDateTime` you're not closing the database by any chance, are you?

Comment: dbcon.updateDateTime is another method ,am updating table with some strings